# One Client with two server socket connection python

Tags: python, sockets

Another Newbie and another newbie question. 
I am writing a python script to connect client to an **open server1 socket** and then process the event received form server1 to open connection to another **open server2 socket**. When i try to run the following script it gives WinError 10056.

This winerror was taken care of by opening 2 sockets. Thanks to @aminrd. 
Now, i want to process the binary event that i receive from server 1 and process this event to trigger server2. There can be multiple binary events that i can receive from server1. The way i know to match them and trigger s2 connection is how i have written in the script below. I am sure there is much better way of collecting the binary event codes in 1 event_list and then iterating over them to trigger s2. Thank you for guiding.

```
import socket

SHOST = 'xx.xx.xx.xx'  # server1 IP address
SPORT = xxxx # The port used by the server1
VHOST = 'xx.xx.xx.xx'  # server2 IP
VPORT = xxxxx# server2 Port
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((SHOST, SPORT))  # connection to server1
data = s.recv(1024)
print('Received', repr(data))

MESSAGE1 = b''  # send login credentials
s.send(MESSAGE1)
print('Received', repr(data))
MESSAGE2 = b''  # activate the events
s.send(MESSAGE2)
print('Received', repr(data))

while True:
    events: bytes = s.recv(1024)
    event_list1 = b'1015'
    event_list2 = b'1127'
    if events.find(event_list1) != -1:
        print(f'EVENT RECEIVED: Badge Authorized')
        s.connect((VHOST, VPORT))
        s.sendall(hex('015A303002534143354104'))
    elif events.find(event_list2) != -1:
        print(f'EVENT RECEIVED: Unassigned Badge')
    else:
        print(repr(events))
```

Comment: Have you tried opening two different sockets `s1, s2` and connect `s1` to `SHOST` and `s2` to `VHOST`?

Comment: @aminrdThank you for pointing that out. I think now it opens another socket for server2 connection using 

s1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s2 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

i hope this is right.

Comment: That's right. And then `s1.connect((SHOST, SPORT))` and `s2.connect((VHOST, VPORT))`. After that you can send and receive the data separately for each one.